# Closed form expression for the area of the shadow of an ellipsoid subject to light rays from a point light source

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, quadrics

An ellipsoid with equation

$ (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r_0} )^T Q (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r_0} ) = 1 $

is subject to light rays from an omni-directional light (light source emitting light rays in all directions).  The light source is located at $\mathbf{p_0}$.  I'd like to find a closed form expression for the area of the shadow of this ellipse cast on the the plane $\mathbf{n}^T (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r_1} ) = 0 $.  It is assumed that the ellipsoid lies between the light source and the plane.

**My approach** is detailed in my answer below.

Your comments, or alternative solutions, are highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll outline the method I used to find the closed form expression of the area of the shadow.

Step 1:  Transform the ellipsoid into a unit sphere centered at the origin.  The cone of light becomes a right circular cone.

Step 2:  Find the area of the shadow of the shadow in the transformed coordinates by intersecting the transformed plane with the right circular cone resulting from the transformation.

Step 3:  From the area found in Step 2, and the distance between the transformed light source location and the transformed plane, calculate the volume of the cut right circular cone.

Step 4:  Calculate the volume of the original elliptical cone of shadow cast by the ellipsoid, by reversing the effect of the transformation.

Step 5:  Calculate the distance between the light source and the given plane, and from the formula for the volume of a cone (which is now known, from Step 4), calculate the area of the base.

I will not put all the details of the above steps.  However, the final result is as follows:

Define $\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{p_0} - \mathbf{r_0} $ and $\mathbf{ w }= \mathbf{p_0} - \mathbf{r_1} $

Then the area of the shadow is given by

$ A_{\text{shadow}} = \pi \dfrac{( \mathbf{n}^T \mathbf{w} )^2 \sqrt{ \mathbf{v}^T Q \mathbf{v} - 1 }} { \sqrt{\det(Q)} ( (\mathbf{n}^T \mathbf{v} )^2 -  \mathbf{n}^T Q^{-1} \mathbf{n} )^{(3/2)}} $